# How do detect back press when the cursor is in the EditText in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard

I needed to detect back press when the cursor is in the EditText.

When user press back, it hide soft keyboard. I needed to do some other functionality when soft key board hides.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a Custom EditText and override the **onKeyPreIme** method like below :

```
package com.fi.stackoverflow

import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

class CustomEditText : AppCompatEditText {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {}
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {}

    override fun onKeyPreIme(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // you can do your action Here
            Toast.makeText(context,"Try to hide KeyBoard",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true // true if you don't want to hide the KeyBoard and False otherwise
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event)
    }
}
```

and in you xml file use it like below (don't forget to change your package name)

```
<com.fi.stackoverflow.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/inputEditor"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>
```

and this in my Activity

```
   val editText = findViewById<CustomEditText>(R.id.inputEditor);
```

Comment: Not working. Showing error "'onKeyPreIme' overrides nothing"

Comment: Maybe you've extended the EditText not the AppCompatEditText @JishnuNKrishnan